# FTP FtpWebRequest uploader corrupting exe files

Tags: c#, .net, ftp, binary, ftpwebrequest

I have a simple FTP uploader (mostly not my own code, still learning) 
It works just fine but it is corrupting exe files, from my reading around that is because it's not a binary reader. But what is confusing is that I am telling it to use binary.

This is my code:

```
private void UploadFileToFTP(string source)
{
    String sourcefilepath = textBox5.Text;
    String ftpurl = textBox3.Text; // e.g. ftp://serverip/foldername/foldername
    String ftpusername = textBox1.Text; // e.g. username
    String ftppassword = textBox2.Text; // e.g. password

    try
    {
        string filename = Path.GetFileName(source);
        string ftpfullpath = ftpurl + "/" + new FileInfo(filename).Name;
        FtpWebRequest ftp = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(ftpfullpath);
        ftp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpusername, ftppassword);

        ftp.KeepAlive = true;
        ftp.UseBinary = true;
        ftp.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

        FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(source);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[fs.Length];
        fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        fs.Close();

        Stream ftpstream = ftp.GetRequestStream();
        ftpstream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        ftpstream.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean it works fine but corrupts exe files?  How does it work fine if it's corrupting files?

Comment: Because the actual function of uploading works for most file types. apart from .exes

Comment: Then is sounds like an encoding issue. Perhaps OpenRead() does something funky to the encoding. Try my example below. I just tested it with an EXE and it worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

`Stream.Read` does not guarantee you to read all bytes you have requested.

Specifically [`FileStream.Read` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream.read) says:

> count: The **maximum** number of bytes to read.
>   Return Value: The total number of bytes read into the buffer. This **might be less** than the number of bytes requested if that number of bytes are not currently available, or zero if the end of the stream is reached.

---

To read whole file to memory, use [`File.ReadAllBytes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readallbytes):

```
byte[] buffer = File.ReadAllBytes(source);
```

Though you should actually use [`Stream.CopyTo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.copyto), to avoid storing huge files completely to memory:

```
fs.CopyTo(ftp.GetRequestStream());
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what issue you're having.

This code works just fine for me:

```
String sourcefilepath = "";
String ftpurl = ""; // e.g. ftp://serverip/foldername/foldername
String ftpusername = ""; // e.g. username
String ftppassword = ""; // e.g. password
var filePath = "";
try
{
    string filename = Path.GetFileName(sourcefilepath);
    string ftpfullpath = ftpurl + "/" + new FileInfo(filename).Name;
    FtpWebRequest ftp = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(ftpfullpath);
    ftp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpusername, ftppassword);

    ftp.KeepAlive = true;
    ftp.UseBinary = true;
    ftp.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

    byte[] buffer = File.ReadAllBytes(sourcefilepath);

    ftp.ContentLength = buffer.Length;

    Stream ftpstream = ftp.GetRequestStream();
    ftpstream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    ftpstream.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
```

Comment: I used this, but it still works. Thanks a bunch dude:

 byte[] buffer = new byte[fs.Length];
                fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                ftp.ContentLength = fs.Length;
                fs.Close();

Comment: Awkward.. :| . I didn't know that. Thanks for the link.